# How to move Application.Resources to external assembly?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, app.xaml

Suppose I have `App.xaml` with following content:

```
[...]
<Application.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Theme.CheckBox.Border}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Theme.Foreground}" />
  </Style>
</Application.Resources>
[...]
```

Now, I want to move those definitions to external assembly. This way I can reuse WPF controls and window styles across my applications. For example I could create NuGet package and install those styles in seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a simple `classLibrary` project, Define all your styles and templates etc, in separated resource dictionaries (recommended) and merge all those dictionaries into one dictionary.

To use those styles from that specific assembly just refer to it in your **App.Xaml** file,

The following shots should gave you a global view

[image]

I am used to create a separate `ResourceDictionary` for each `style` (for easy access), and all those resource dictionaries are merged in the **ResourceLibrary.Xaml**

[image]

Now to refere to that **ControlLibraryAssembly** (after adding a reference to it), in your **app.xaml** file add

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/ControlLibrary;component/ResourcesDictionaries/ResourceLibrary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>            
    </ResourceDictionary>        
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: more hints and best practices from this awesome post http://projekt202.com/blog/2010/xaml-organization/

Comment: That's a super clean approach to organization of XAML files!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make resource assembly. Here you can read how you can create it:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984332(v=vs.71).aspx